# Type int is not a subtype of type string Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to return an int data as a string from firebase but I don't know how? I tried toString() but maybe there is more I have to do?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // <1> Use FutureBuilder
    return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        // <2> Pass `Future<QuerySnapshot>` to future
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserNames').get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // <3> Retrieve `List<DocumentSnapshot>` from snapshot
            final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data.docs;
            return ListView(
                children: documents
                    .map((doc) => Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(doc['displayName']),
                            subtitle: Text(doc['plastics']),
                          ),
                        ))
                    .toList());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Its Error!');
          }
        });
  }
```

The doc plastics is where the error is from as that is an int value in firestore.  How do I convert an int data to a text?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways and nothing more you can do :)

1. `toString()` method

> doc['plastics'].toString()

2. String interpolation

> '${doc['plastics']}'